# Can I use 18 AWG thermostat wire for led strip lights

Tags: led, low-voltage

I'm planning to add LED strip lights as under cabinet lighting. The driver and the strip lights I got has 20AWG wires. Can I use the 18 AWG thermostat wire to wire between the driver and the strip lights? I'm going to be concealing the wires in the wall, and since the thermostat wire is thicker it should be fine. But then again, please do tell me if I shouldn't do this.

Comment: Just to confirm, these are 12v or 24v strips? If so, the wire will be fine.

Comment: 12V DC, 12W output from the driver

Comment: Gauge is perfectly fine.  Only caveat is that the wire must be CL2 for in-wall use.  Since it's tstat wire, one might assume that's the case.  Where will the driver be located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wire gauges are physically smaller the larger the number is, and vice versa.

So, 18 AWG is larger than 20 AWG.

While 120/240V circuits in the US may not use wires smaller than 14 AWG, low voltage lighting is not so constrained.

Thus, 18 AWG is perfectly fine for use in your low-voltage lighting application, if anything somewhat superior to (lower resistance than) using 20 AWG.

Comment: I've very successfully used small speaker wire for powering under-counter LED light strips of short lengths (i.e. under 5 feet of total length), so I think thermostat wire should be fine as well.

Comment: Agree, I use 18/3 for addressable 12v christmas light runs of up to 60 feet and it works fine.

Answer (score 6):

### You need to do a *voltage drop calculation*

Ones inclination is to think "Small voltage, small wire size!"  But actually, it's the other way 'round.

Low voltage loads are much more sensitive to voltage drop for a couple of reasons.  First, if you have 3 volts of voltage drop, that's of little concern on a 120V circuit, but a big concern on a 12V circuit.  Second, voltage drop (in volts, not percent) is proportional to *amps*, and when you reduce voltage for a given load, you increase amps in proportion.  This creates a quadratic effect that makes voltage drop an issue much sooner than you would intuitively expect.

There are plenty of voltage drop calculators online, and there are voltage drop charts used for marine - though they may not go as low as #18.

Comment: What's a reasonable threshold above which a person needs to be concerned about voltage drop? Most kitchens aren't going to see wire runs longer than 30 ft or so.

Comment: @isherwood It would be *maybe* 5'.  It happens real fast.

Comment: Comment states 12V, 12W, so 1A (and that's probably maximum for the supply - the connected load may draw less) and in 5 feet of 18 AWG that's a non-horrifying 0.53%

Comment: Likewise, for typical examples of strip lights, the calculation is non-trivial (or it's wrong if simplified) because the further you get from the source, the less current is being drawn, as there are fewer LEDs beyond where you are now.

Comment: @Ecnerwal my rule of thumb is +4 wire sizes means half the amps, so 18 AWG is probably 7.5A wire with a 6A continuous load.  If 5 feet of #18 is 0.53% per amp, then it's over 3% at 6 amps.  I'm assuming a blind run of wire to the first lamp and disregarding "down the lamp" numbers, but I've run those too and it's enough to make an observable difference down a 16' LED strip. I've unrolled them and tried.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot properly answer your question as you did not state the wire length or the current the LED(s) will be drawing. A 2% drop would be noticeable if other LED(s) are powered from the same source and in close proximity to each other. This [calculator](https://www.wirebarn.com/Wire-Calculator-_ep_41.html) will help you determine what you need.  From this you can calculate what the end voltage is, and the voltage drop at whatever percentage you want to tolerate.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you need to look at the AWG of wire relative to length to see what the resistance of the wire is for a given length and calculate the voltage drop. However, from my end, the question isn’t will it work as much as safety. You’ll also also want to calculate the maximum current that’ll be passing through the 18 AWG wire and make sure that is less than the maximum (sounds like in-wall) current capacity of your application. A smaller wire means more resistance which equates to a specific amount of heat release. Note that depending where you’re at, even low voltage uses of wire can have regulations for in-wall wire. If your wire isn’t in-wall rated you may run into issues. These regulations exist because improper wire can release toxic fumes and/or act as a line for spreading fire in the instance one occurs.

Note: Given the device wire is 20 AWG, this suggests 18 AWG is likely safe, but you should do your own current draw calculations to make sure.